# IE9 opening new tab after using clicks on onpage anchor link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Ive got a intermittent bug where in IE9 on where ive got a one page website using on page anchor links for users to jump between sections. It works fine cross browser but in IE9 somtimes instead of moving to the relevant section it will just load up the same page again in a new tab. Any ideas why this might be happening ?

Im not very fussed about the bug as IE9 is being [unsupported by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle#gp/Microsoft-Internet-Explorer) in all desktops but Windows Vista SP2 after 16/1/16. So im sure the residual usage will begin to drop off even further, but it would be good to know if there is a solution for this either way.

These are coded like this :

```
<ul style="">
                <li>
                    <a href="#section2">EXAMPLE</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#section4">LOREM</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#section6">IPSUM</a>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Im using `<!doctype html>`.

Ive only tested this in Windows 7 not any other OS as my test suite only has IE9 in W7, but i guess its present in others.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an intranet site or is the website being viewed in compatibility mode? Tools > Compatibility View Settings
- If so, try removing it from compatibility view mode or unchecking "Display intranet sites in "Compatibility View"

Also, I've seen strange issues occur with some add-ons. Have you tried disabling all add-ons?
Start > Run > iexplore -extoff

If that works then I would try systematically disabling add-ons (E.g. Google Voice, any toolbars, LastPass, or any add-ons that are non-Microsoft).

I hope this helps!